# Изображения какого формата быстрее загружаются из ресурсов?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день на кнопках есть иконки , хотелось бы узнать что Андроид быстрее подгружает из ресурсов `jpeg`,`png` или вектор `svg`

Comment: Не думаю что есть однозначный ответ.

Comment: если под `подгружает из ресурсов` подразумевается и время отрисовки, то растр определенно будет отрисован быстрее вектора.

Comment: @ermak0ff, вообще-то не факт. Это было бы верно в случае простого растра вроде bmp, но форматы с серьезной компрессией требуют довольно серьезной обработки.

Comment: Из перечисленных png наименее затратен по растеризации

Comment: @freim `The initial loading of a vector drawable can cost more CPU cycles than the corresponding raster image.` https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio

Comment: @ermak0ff, "_can cost_" это "_может стоить_". А может и не стоить. А самое главное, там говорится о PSD файлах. PSD это довольно примитивные битмэпы, никакой продвинутой компрессии там нет. Обычно простейшее RLE. JPG и PNG это другое дело, отрисовать вектор будет быстрее чем распаковать jpeg.

Comment: @freim статья с бенчмарком - https://upday.github.io/blog/vector_drawables_optimisation/

Comment: @ermak0ff, а вы ее читали? :) Она для иконок (а вопрос у нас, напомню, про иконки) рекомендует как раз вектор вместо png (про jpeg даже речь не идет).  Причем и в этом случае имелась некоторая ловкость рук с измерениями - вроде везде упоминается png, а измерения производятся уже с чистым декодированным растром. Вообще я спорить не хочу потому что сам никаких измерений не проводил. Просто есть сомнения насчет того, что растр с учетом декодирования на маленьких изображениях будет быстрее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не знаю что там насчет сравнения производительности `PNG/JPG` - занятие очевидно неблагодарное, но тем не менее:

1. `JPEG` дает более высокую степень сжатия за счет использования особенностей человеческого зрения, но и математика сжатия там сложнее поскольку применяется быстрое преобразование Фурье
2. В противовес ему `PNG` применяет алгоритм сжатия без потерь с относительно простой математикой
3. В итоге: при прочих равных условиях `JPEG` маленький файл, но более сложен в математике при отрисовке, `PNG` соответственно, размер файла больше, но математика (вычислительно) попроще.

`SVG` вообще за скобками - поскольку это векторный формат: пытаться сравнивать растр с вектором, все равно что сравнивать *круглое с красным*

Гораздо более важно (мне кажется) замечание ТС:

> что андроид быстрее подгружает из ресурсов

В Андроид для хранения бинарных файлов есть 2 типа ресурсов: каталоги `res` и `asset`.

По скорости доступа к ним `res` конечно впереди, поскольку после инсталляции это превращается просто в файлы, а `asset` при инсталляции превращаются в записи в БД SQLite... Так что для разворачивания `asset` требуется еще и лишний оверхед в виде чтения из БД.

В целом, я полагаю, что наиболее эффективно с точки зрения скорости разворачивания хранить изображения в формате `PNG` в каталоге `res`